# Wait until condition in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

How to put a wait condition in selenium web-driver for assert load. I want to test a web application, that application have background audio.

I can able to write a wait condition for DOM element is loaded or not. But how can I put wait condition for audio file whether it was fully loaded or not.

Comment: is there a javascript code that plays the audio file? When the audio file starts playing, do you notice any change in the code?

Comment: This is react js application. Audios are auto play while page was load, .mp3   request also pass to the server while page in loading state..

Comment: What I am trying is, I export a HAR file from a web application using selenium, from this HAR file i can able to take all HTTP request's size and load time, but can't able to take .mp3 request's size. That .mp3 request in 206 status. That's why i want wait my webdriver audio got fully loaded state.

Answer (score 0):

wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(yourlocator));

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.